# Dealing with JSON fields that can come with values of different types, Android

Tags: json, retrofit2, android, gson

When I fetch a listing from reddit using this endpoint: `https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/new/.json`, I get a list of posts, which have a field `edited` that comes with `false` if the post hasn't been edited yet, or with a timestamp long if it has.

How can I deserialize this listing properly using Retrofit and Gson in order to take this type difference into account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this out:

```
    public class PostDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Post> {
    @Override
     public Post deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
       throws JsonParseException {

        boolean notEdited = json.get("edited").getAsString().notEquals("False");

       if (notEdited) {
            json.remove("edited")
        }

        //create new Post and then return it

   }
}
```

Comment: You should extends instead of implements `JsonDeserializer` class